# What's the difference between "til 9.00" and "before 9.00"?

Tags: time

I was sent a text "I will be home til 9.00" and I understood it to mean before 9.00 but I can't explain how to use til, until, by or before. I thought til was used with negative words (I won't be home til 9.00) but that's not always true (eg I'll be at work til 9.00).

Answer (score 0):

"I will be home til 9.00" means "I will be at home **until** 9.00", at which point they presumably are leaving.

"til" is a contraction of "until" and therefore should have an apostrophe like

*I will be home 'til 9.00"*

(*"I **won't** be home 'til 9:00"* means *"I will be out, ie not at home, until 9:00".*)

"by" on the other hand, has almost the opposite meaning to "until" in this context:  if someone says *"I'll be home by 9.00"* they mean that *"At some point before 9:00 I will **arrive** home"*: so it's like saying *"I will be home from 9:00 onwards"*.

*"I will be home before 9:00"* could actually mean **either of the above things**:  it could mean *"I will be home during the period which is before 9:00"* or it could mean *"I will arrive home before 9:00"*.

I think the second usage is more common, but there's no way to definitively say which is which: it's an example of where you need to use the context to make a judgement about what someone means.